# Passing a list of records to an invocable method

Tags: visual-workflow, invocable-method

The [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.210.0.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_annotation_InvocableMethod.htm) on `invocableMethod` clearly states that you can pass in a list of a sObject type.

> There can be at most one input parameter and its data type must be one of the following: 
>   A list of a primitive data type or a list of lists of a primitive data type – the generic Object type is not supported.
>   A list of an sObject type or a list of lists of an sObject type – the generic sObject type is not supported.

However, in my flow, i only have the option to pass in a sObject variable - there is no option to pass in a sObject collection (I have a sObject collection set to public input / output in the flow).

[image: optionsInFlowApexElement]

So how can you pass a list of a sObject type from flow to invocable method?  Seems like you can only pass a single sObject.

Answer (score 1):

Found answer on [developer boards](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000005GQdIAM) from Chad Barbour.

> If the expectation is to receive a collection you can use in the flow, you'll need to have your method return a collection of collections. In this case, if you're wanting a list of strings (List), you'll want to have it return a list containing lists of strings (List>).

Apparently a sObject variable is a list, and a sObject collection is a list of lists.  So you need to be able to work with lists of lists and then you will have the option to pass / receive sObject collections.  Go figure...

Comment: also in this sfse post : https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/76787/flow-invocablemethod-how-to-assign-output-to-collection-sobject-collection-v/160173#160173

Answer (score 0):

In your invocable method, set the incoming parameter to a list of lists of your object type.  Ex:  `List<List<Leads>>`, save the class and reload Flow to see if you can pass in a collection. I also asked a similar question that has code showing invocable variables [here.](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/281216/creating-test-class-for-apex-reports-namespace-used-in-flow-action) I was able to pass in collections once I used invokable variables to communicate with flow.